# 'didSelectRowAt' is not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have a question about the `UITableView` delegate function `didSelectRowAt`. Everything is working fine but unfortunately the `didSelectRowAt` is not called. I read in some other stackoverflow question about the problem and tried some solutions out but none of them works for me. I made a subclass of the tableview which is the delegate himself:

```
class MyTableView : UITableView, UITableViewDelegate{

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        super.awakeFromNib()

        separatorStyle = .none

        backgroundView = nil
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        isScrollEnabled = false

        delegate = self
        isEditing = false
        allowsSelection = true

    }


//    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//       
//    this is working        
//
//    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("not called")

    }    

}
```

So all subclasses of `MyTableView` will implement the datasource stuff and this also working fine (in case somehow will mentioned this).

The strange thing is that `didHighlightRowAt` is called, so the delegate somehow works. Only the `didSelectRowAt` which I want is not being called.

By the way there aren't any `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Can somehow give me any advice here. Are there properties which are wrong?

Comment: make sure your cell has user interaction  enabled

Comment: check Tableview cells are selectable & check user interaction enabled or not?

Comment: Do you have any `UITapGestureRecognizer` in your view controller?

Comment: Don’t subclass `UITableView` . That way lies pain and burning. Use a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` or a plain `UITableViewController`.

Answer (score 46):

If you have a parent view with gesture recognizer assigned to it you'll need to do something like this:

```
self.tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: action)
if let tapGestureRecognizer = self.tapGestureRecognizer {
  tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
  self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}
```

Once you told the gesture recognizer to stop canceling touches, your UITableView starts reacting on taps as normal

Comment: Thank you! This one solved it. I have a gesture recognizer in my superview and it causes problems.

Comment: Super useful. Thanks!

Comment: .cancelsTouchesInView saved me

Comment: Thanks! What was ultra-weird is that didHighlightRowAt was being called even when I had not set this flag. Occasionally didSelectRowAt would be called as well, especially if I had a breakpoint in the debugger in didHighlightRowAt.

Comment: Exactly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 34):

Please check `TableView's` cell allowsSelection.

```
tableView.allowsSelection = true
```

---

Edit:

### Check:

- tableView.allowsSelection
- cell.selectionStyle
- User Interaction Enabled

Comment: Also checked this one. It's set to .default like taken from this breakpoint: currentCell.selectionStyle (UITableViewCellSelectionStyle) default

Answer (score 21):

For me, changing selection style, from none, solved the problem.

[image: storyboard]

Answer (score 12):

If your `ViewController` has `UIGestureRecognizer` You should disable `UIGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView`. For example:

```
 extension UIViewController {

    public func hideKeyboarOnTap() {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyboardAction))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc private func hideKeyboardAction() {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

There might be the following issue  s:

1. You have not setup the delegate of the UITableView

```
self.tableview.delegate = self
```

2. Check if the user-interaction is no disable for UITableView or UITableViewCell

```
self.tableview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

3. Check if the tableview selection style is not none

```
self.tableview.allowsSelection = true
```

4. Check if any of the gestures are not enabled.

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool { 
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest writing replace this on your code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableview.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. An explanation of how your answer addresses the issue is always useful.

Answer (score 3):

I added a mechanism to hide keyboard when tapping out of text field:

```
    ...

    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSingleTap(recognizer:)))
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
}

@objc func handleSingleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

The `handleSingleTap` stole the event. I removed everything above, and used this instead:

```
override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

And editing came back!

Answer (score 2):

I dont know what others solutions you tried, but if you are using a custom viewcell , it might be that you didint enable **"User Interaction Enabled"** on that component.

Comment: I double checked it. It's enabled. I made a break point in the didHighlightRowAt function (which is working) to check the isUserInteractionEnabled property.

Comment: I checked it with an example code and it's working fine. Pretty sure that it's related to your Custom UITableViewCell. make sure to disable any user interaction enabled in your subviews.

Answer (score 1):

I the same problem, even though the delegate was setup correctly. In my case, it was not possible to interact with the table view because it was not the fist subview from the user's perspective. You can make sure it is displayed in front by using this method when you add it to your main view:

`view.insertSubview(yourTableView, at: self.view.subviews.count)`

or bring it to the front using this:

`self.view.bringSubview(toFront: yourTableView)`

Answer (score 1):

For me some views was blocking each other and because i've set `tableView:shouldHighlightRowAt:` to `false` i wasn't able to detect the problem

Answer (score 1):

check you `didSelectRowAt` method may be you have typo did**De**selectRowAtIndexPath

There is a chance you accidentally typed `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Wow.  That happened to me 'didDeselectRowAt', and you helped me find the bug. Easy to select the wrong one in a hurry from the xcode function prototypes

Answer (score 0):

**Objective C - Possible Solutions:**

1. You just have to use:

   **tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;**

**Code:**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                           initWithTarget:self
                           action:@selector(yourFunctionOnTap)];
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

2. Set allow selection property of tableview

`tableView.allowsSelection = true`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. A tableview, embedded in a container view that, in turn was collapsable (via a UIPanGestureRecognizer).

Turned out that, in addition to `tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false` and the delegate's `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith`, also had to set `tap.delaysTouchesBegan = true`.

Apparently, some sort of race condition between all the recognizer's around.